# hierarchical pathfinding implementation

Tags: artificial-intelligence, path-finding, hierarchical

I want to divide my map in clusters and implement HPA*. Where do I start, each time I try this I run into problems. I need to implement this on a random and dynamically changing map.

I am unsure how to write an algorithm that places these "nodes", to connect the parts, in between sections/clusters of the map and update them. I guess every time open tiles lie in between closed tiles on the edge of a cluster/section there should be a node since inside the cluster it could be that multiple openings into the cluster do not connect to each other within this section.

Normally I would just have a big Tile[,] map. I guess I could just leave this be and create a cluster/section class that holds all the paths and nodes. And have a node class/struct that holds the 2 tiles that are connected between sections. I have read several articles about HPA* but I just can not wrap my head around implementing this correctly on a random and dynamical map. I hope to get some good pointers here although the question is not very clear.

-edit-
What i am trying to do is making cluster class that holds 10x10 tiles/nodes with on each side an entry point (several if there is a obstruction on the edge). The entries link to the next cluster.

Comment: Could you be a bit more clear on what you've tried, and what you're having trouble with?  You should already have a graph of nodes without HPA\* - HPA\* just takes those nodes and groups them into sets, so you can search over those sets instead of the individual nodes (greatly reducing the search-space, but causing it to be non-optimal).

Comment: See also [the paper on HPA\*](http://abotea.rsise.anu.edu.au/data/hpastar.pdf), [the paper on HAA\*](http://harablog.files.wordpress.com/2009/01/haa.pdf), [this article explaining HAA\* in simpler terms](http://aigamedev.com/open/article/clearance-based-pathfinding/) or [this gamedev.SE answer giving a brief overview of HPA\*](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/32831/2061).

Comment: My question is how do the individual sets know they are linked together. There are case where you need to go to a neighbor set but need a large detour. Or am i totally mistaken and do these methods just  perform better because the algorithm cant spread that far?

Comment: You simply pre-calculate the distance between each entry(/exit) node in a set to get the edge-lengths in the HPA\* graph.  This may cause sub-optimal detours - that's why the algorithm is non-optimal.

Comment: So i should add the property entry to my nodes and flag this if it is a entry point. Now i need a algorithm for putting all these entry nodes in a random map.

Comment: Er, well no, you should be building a separate graph.  Please see one of the linked papers/articles for more information.